# how to change the whole screen color in react?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am working in react I want to know that how we can change the whole body color or background color because the backgroundColor is just change the backgroundColor of the content like I am writing

```
<div style="backgroundColor:black">
  <p >hello</p>
</div>
```

It change the background color of `"hello"` how I can change the whole backround color?

Answer (score 0):

You can write variables in your css file,so you can provide the same variable to any component whose color you want to change along with body

```
:root {
  --blue: #1e90ff;
}

body { background-color: var(--blue); }
otherelement{ background-color: var(--blue); }
```

Also you can update that color variable dynamically as shown below

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--blue', "red");
```